# Syntax Error When Running paster?

Tags: python, syntax, pyramid, paster

No idea what happened, but all of a sudden, paster stopped working on my server (working with virtualenv and pyramid). Tried reinstalling everything but didn't work - same error again:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/paster", line 7, in ?
    sys.exit(
  File "/home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.4.egg/paste/script/command.py", line 83, in run
    command = commands[command_name].load()
  File "/home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.4.egg/paste/script/serve.py", line 19, in ?
     from paste.deploy import loadapp, loadserver
  File "/home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/__init__.py", line 3, in ?
    from paste.deploy.loadwsgi import *
  File "/home/user/webapps/myapp/htdocs/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PasteDeploy-1.5.0-py2.4.egg/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 393
    with open(filename) as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is happening to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Python 2.4. It does not have the `with` statement. It only came in Python 2.5.

Update your version of Python.